# Sending Extra Data from BroadcastReceiver Context is Null

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm just trying to figure out how Services, BroadcastReceivers and all that stuff works.

I wrote a Receiver which triggers, when the screen state changes. Than it opens a Service, which opens an Activity that is placed over the lock screen. That works fine as long as my App is running, but when my App is dead, the context that is handed to my BroadcastReceiver is null. And than I can't transfer my Data to the Service because the Intent is null as well.

I hope someone knows how to fix that.

My Code looks as follows:

Activity that starts the Service:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent service = new Intent(this,UpdateService.class);
    startService(service);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The Service:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags , int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {
        // Screen is on
    } else {
        // Screen is off
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
        // The Flag is important to open an Acitivy from the service.
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }
    Intent intent2open;
    intent2open = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    intent2open.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
    context.startService(intent2open);
}
```

}

Comment: Just asking but how do u plan to launch your activity on the lock screen?

Comment: The plan is, that the Service starts the Activity with this lines of Code:
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
        // The Flag is important to open an Acitivy from the service.
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

I think you would do better to register your Receiver directly in the Manifest and change `this` to maybe `getApplicationContext()` or Start an activity to start the `Intent` but make sure it uses the `finish()` method so users wont even know another activity was called!

**EDIT:**

I think I understand what your problem is. I have modified your code and also removed the service because I don't think it is required.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle.savedInstanceState) {

public boolean ScreenState =     true; 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent    intent) { 
 ScreenState =     intent.getExtra("screen_state"))
if(ScreenState==false)
 { 
      //**Do whatever you want**
 }
 else
{
     //False alarm close the activity.
     finish();
}
}
```

Your broadcast receiver.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context.   context, Intent intent){

if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    screenOff = true;
  } else if.   (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    screenOff = false;
  }
Intent intent2open;
intent2open = new Intent(context, **My Activity**.class);
   intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent2open.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
context.startActivity(intent2open);
}
}
```

Let me know if this works.
Remember the broadcast receiver to change **My Activity** to the name of your activity.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your Answer. My Receiver is registered in the Manifest and so is the Service:

 <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".UpdateService"
            android:exported="false" />

Which this do you mean? In the Service or in the Activity? And would this help with the Problem that I'm receiving a null object?

Comment: If it's already registered in the manifest why are you even registering in the service. All you want to do is whenever there is a screen on or so open an activity right?

Comment: @Eric the above code should work please see the edit and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hello KISHORE_ZE, thanks for your Effort. I don't know where I should place the onNewIntent Method. I tried to use the code without the service and it worked, but only when the App was running in the background. But I don't want the App to run in the Background. It should be as follows:

User starts the App once and sees Activity "A", than he closes the App.
Than, always when he turns the Screen off, Activity "B" is started, which is placed in Front of the Lockscreen. But the Context which the BroadcastReceiver receives is null when the App is closed and than I can't transmit the Screenstate.

Comment: `onNewIntent` is placed in the class. Before `onCreate()` if you wish for a particular place. Ok then let me compile this code myself and check.

Comment: BTW is it registered in Mainfest

Comment: I am really very sorry but I tried everything. Finally I accomplished that the broadcast receiver always ran in the background. But it did not have enough details,i.e, context properly to open Activity B. Looks like that way will only work when registered in the Manifest and unfortunately Broadcast Receiver for SCREEN_ON cannot be registered in the Manifest. I am sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: There could be a way actually. Try passing the context of your activity to your broadcast receiver. I JUST GOT THAT IDEA PLEASE TRY AND LET ME KNOW